# No of triangles in a square which contains all the m points?

Tags: geometry

Given a square $A(0,0)$, $B(0,n)$, $C(n,n)$ and $D(0,n)$ in $X­Y$ plane and a set of $m$ points. The $m$ points strictly lie inside the square $ABCD$. It is clear that there are $4n$ integer points on the contour of the square $ABCD$. Count the number of triangles whose vertices are chosen from the $4n$ points and enclose all the $m$ points.

Comment: Do we know anything about the $m$ inside points? Or are you looking for an (efficient) algorithm that will. given the $m$ points, do the counting?

Answer (score 1):

Write the 3 lines defining the sides of the triangle in terms of the vertices, and write each line as $ax + by = c$ where $ax + by \leq c$ defines the interior of the triangle. Then you want the maximum of $ax + by$ over the $m$ points to be less than or equal to $c$ for each side of the triangle. This is the if and only if condition for the $m$ points to all be inside the triangle. This should allow you to characterize and count the triangles containing the points potentially without having to try them all one by one.

Comment: You have to do a little bit more. You have to keep track of which side of each line contains the inside of the triangle. Given a single side of the triangle, you can’t necessarily determine which side is the inside and which side is the outside of a triangle with one side on that line whose remaining vertex could be on either side of the line. Consequently, you don’t know for each side whether you want the maximum to be $\le c$ or the minimum to be $\ge c$. As long as you keep track of this, though, what you suggest can work.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s another tip that might help.

Given a triangle $ABC$, suppose you want to know if the point $P$ is inside or outside the triangle. Compute this sum of three *directed* angle measurements: $\angle APB + \angle BPA + \angle CPA$. If the point is inside the triangle, this sum will be $\pm2\pi$. If the point is outside the triangle, the sum will be $0$. (Up to the $2\pi$ multiple, this is the “winding number” of the oriented triangle about the point.)

You must be careful to compute the directed angles, which can be between $-\pi$ and $\pi$. One way to do it is with the two-argument inverse tangent function called $\mbox{atan2}$ in many programming languages. The directed angle (the bearing) from $\vec u = (x_1,y_1)$ to $\vec v=(x_2,y_2)$ is $\mbox{atan2}(\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v},|\vec{u}\times\vec{v}|)$, where $\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}=x_1x_2+y_1y_2$ and $|\vec{u}\times\vec{v}|=x_1y_2-y_1x_2$ are the dot product and the magnitude of the cross product.